# @vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT with laravel 10 react

Tags: laravel, vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axAkg.png)

I got this error when I run my project on LAN.

I try to change vite.config.js
this is my code

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({

    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.jsx',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),
    ],
    server: {
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost',//I tried to change it to 127.0.0.1 or my LAN IPV4
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to not use images when ever possible a quick copy and paste would have worked. That or a straight image instead of a link.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I can't upload image normal

Comment: No problem man, just want you to get your answer asap. Lots of folks will skip over the question if it doesn't have sufficient or well formatted/detail. Then stop by just to down vote making it even worse.

Comment: Just kind of noticing why are you attempting to load files outside of your public directory from the browser? You should be packaging/bundling them to your public directory for access. If you didn't do this people could access directories on your public server and cause all sorts of havoc. The assumption I think is that you would server up your null route to start with compiled components referenced in them in your app.js in most likely in your resource directory.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Laravel Sail, open the vite.config.js file and configure it like so:

```
export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [
        react(),
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.jsx'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
      ], 
      server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
      }
    });
```

Comment: I try but not working.